# Appending row to a dataframe makes the column labels to the index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append, concatenation

I am somehow stuck here at the moment, I have an (in the beginning empty) dataframe `df_ben_Boxen`, to which I want to add the rows of `df_Box_Code_Inhalt` if they are containing the same `Artikelnr` as the row in `df_Stueckliste`

At the moment, it writes the index with the column-labels, which isn't what I want.

```
import pandas as pd
df_Box_Code_Inhalt=pd.read_excel("Box_Code_Inhalt.xlsx")
df_ben_Boxen=pd.DataFrame()
def Lade_Zuordnungen(df_ben_Boxen, df_Stueckliste):
    for index, row in df_Stueckliste.iterrows():
        for index2, row in df_Box_Code_Inhalt.iterrows():
            if df_Stueckliste.at[index,"Artikelnr"]==df_Box_Code_Inhalt.at[index2,"Artikelnr"]:
                df_ben_Boxen=pd.concat([df_ben_Boxen,df_Box_Code_Inhalt.loc[index2]],axis=1)
    return df_ben_Boxen
```

Would be nice if some1 could tell me a fix, i am new to python and can't figure it out atm.

[Contents of the original dataframe compared to the changed indexing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPler.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO, people will be able to help you better if you provide [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  You can print df_ben_Boxen.head() and df_Stueckliste.head() and expected output

Comment: Now i tried to accept it this way and transpose the datafield by writing `df_Box_Code_Inhalt.T`but it doesnt switch rows and columns.

Answer (score 0):

I got my problem solved like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df_Box_Code_Inhalt=pd.read_excel("Box_Code_Inhalt.xlsx")
def Lade_Zuordnungen(df_ben_Boxen, df_Stueckliste):
    df_ben_Boxen=pd.read_excel("Box_Code_Inhalt.xlsx")
    df_ben_Boxen.drop(df_ben_Boxen.index, inplace=True)
    for index, row in df_Stueckliste.iterrows():
        for index2, row in df_Box_Code_Inhalt.iterrows():
            if df_Stueckliste.at[index,"Artikelnr"]==df_Box_Code_Inhalt.at[index2,"Artikelnr"]:
                data=list(df_Box_Code_Inhalt.iloc[index2])
                df_ben_Boxen.loc[len(df_ben_Boxen)]=data
    return df_ben_Boxen
```